# Organic Chemistry Exercise Book

Tags: organic-chemistry, books

An Organic Chemistry Book that has only exercises? Better with solutions so to see if the answer is correct. Even more better if there is a PDF version.

The exercises I am looking for are exercises about Hydrocarbons and their reactions, Isomerism exercises, haloalkanes and their reactions, alcohol, eters and thiols, ammines, Fisher's projections and the absolute configuration, sugars, lipids, and proteins.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Martin-マーチン Hello sir! You might want to check it again since it only lists books that have both theory and exercises, and I already use 'Introduction to Organic Chemistry' by Brown for that. I was looking for a book containing exercises **only** as I expressed in my question.

Comment: Well the general problem here is, that book recommendations are somewhat always biased and probably highly opinionated. You might want to be more specific on the topic: organic chemistry is far too broad. You should include examples of what you are looking for specifically.

Comment: @Martin-マーチン I am looking for a book that has all organic chemistry exercises, but exercises only, since I use PDF books and it is very unconfortable to scroll between 200 pages to find different kind of exercises because they are related to the topic they cover, so I think my question was broad because it covers a broad bunch of exercises, simply that sir.

Comment: Yes, and that is exactly the problem. The question is too broad. Please narrow it down. Otherwise it will probably be closed or it will not gather much attention in the first place and will remain unanswered. Take the [tour] to learn more about which questions are on-topic here, please also check the [help]. You can always add more information to your post by [edit]ing it.

Comment: @Martin-マーチン I understand that, but how can I make it another question if this is what I am looking for?

Comment: For example, you could narrow it down to retrosynthesis or reaction mechanisms, or a few functional groups like carbonyl chemistry, organo-catalysis, etc. - OC is quite broad. You will also probably have already some experience with the type of question you are looking for, so you can  include a worked example. Focus on a few things first and hope for answers, if that does not help, come back and ask a new question.

Comment: Geez, go to your library, ask librarian or check shelves. Borrow book...